# lexicographically sort in C

Tags: c, sorting, compare, character, lexicographic

I don't understand how works this sort.Why is it so? And how we compare characters in C , how can I understand which of them less or greater than other? 
It's from book.

*Call the function compareStrings
and have it return the value –1 if the first string is lexicographically less than the secondstring, 0 if the two strings are equal, and 1 if the first string is lexicographically greater
than the second string. So, the function call*

```
compareStrings ("alpha", "altered")
```

*returns the value –1 because the first string is lexicographically less than the second
string (think of this to mean that the first string occurs before the second string in a dictionary).And,
the function call*

```
compareStrings ("zioty", "yucca");
```

*returns the value 1 because “zioty” is lexicographically greater than “yucca.”*

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

struct entry
{
    char word[15];
    char definition[50];
};

bool equalStrings(char s1[], char s2[])
{
    bool areEqual = false;
    int i = 0;

    while(s1[i] != '\0' && s2[i] != '\0' && s1[i] == s2[i])
        i++;

    if(s1[i] == '\0' && s2[i] == '\0')
        areEqual = true;
    else
        areEqual = false;

    return areEqual;
}

int lookup (struct entry dictionary[], char search[],int entries)
{
    int low = 0;
    int high = entries - 1;
    int mid, result;

    while (low <= high)
    {
        mid = (low + high) / 2;
        result = compareStrings (dictionary[mid].word, search);

        if(result == -1)
            low = mid + 1;
        else if(result == 1)
            high = mid - 1;
        else 
            return mid;
    }

    return -1;
}

int compareStrings(char s1[], char s2[])
{
    int i = 0, answer;

    while(s1[i] == s2[i] && s1[i] != '\0' && s2[i] != '\0')
        i++;

    if(s1[i] < s2[i])
        answer = -1;
    else if(s1[i] == s2[i])
        answer = 0;
    else 
        answer = 1;

    return answer;
}

int main()
{
    struct entry dictionary[100] = 
    {
        {"aardvark", "a burrowing African mammal" },
        {"acumen", " a bottomless pit  "},
        {"addle", "to become confused "},
        {"agar", "a jelly made from seaweed" }
        {"affix", "to append; attach"}
    };

    char word[15];
    int entries = 10;
    int entry;

    printf("Enter word: ");
    scanf("%14s", word);
    entry = lookup (dictionary, word, entries);

    if(entry != -1)
        printf("%s\n", dictionary[entry].definition);
    else
        printf("Sorry, the word %s is not in my dictionary.\n", word);

    return 0;

}
```

How understand that one greater than another? Thanks.

Comment: These are the most basic equality checking, comparing and searching algortihms. Did you not understand the algorithms or how you implement them in C? I would suggest you to do more research before you ask for an expert's help.

Comment: I don't understand why we compare last charater in string.And why it calls lexicographically?

Comment: @LittleMax not necessarily the "last" character. Think about that, `while(s1[i] == s2[i] && s1[i] != '\0' && s2[i] != '\0') i++;`, when does the loop end?

Comment: @Stan When characters will be different. But how then compare these characters? Thank you anyway

Comment: @Little Max, char is byte actually. What can't you understand?

Comment: We compare bytes?Or we use ASCII codes for compare characters?

Comment: Оne byte can hold value in range of 0 - 255. Each value represents corresponded character, that's ASCII.

Comment: @Little Max, if you still can't understand then you are a bit in a level of abstraction. C has nothing to do with abstractions in general. Each character is number. It is useful for alphabetical sort. 'B' goes after 'A' because 66 > 65.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lexicographical order is like dictionary order, `a` comes before `b`... with the additional behavior that case matters, uppercase coming before lowercase, and non alphabetic characters also compare based on their encoding.

This comparison is performed character by character. If all characters in both strings are equal, the strings compare equal, the return value is `0`, otherwise the relative order is determined by the comparison of the first mismatched character. If `s1[i] < s2[i]`, string `s1` comes before `s2`, the return value is negative, otherwise `s1` comes after `s2`, the return value is positive.

Note however that this book implementation is sub-optimal and potentially incorrect:

- if `s1[i] == s2[i]` and `s1[i] != '\0'`, comparing `s2[i]` to `'\0'` is redundant.
- characters should be compared as `unsigned char` so extended characters come after regular characters. `strcmp` is specified this way.

Here is a simplified version:

```
int compareStrings(const char *s1, const char *s2) {
    size_t i;

    for (i = 0; s1[i] == s2[i]; i++) {
        if (s1[i] == '\0')
            return 0;
    }
    if ((unsigned char)s1[i] < (unsigned char)s2[i])
        return -1;
    else
        return 1;
}
```

Further notes:

- the `dictionary` defined in `main` is not sorted, `agar` should come after `affix`. The `lookup` function relies on the array of `entry` structures being sorted. It might not find the correct entry for some input words.
- the `lookup` function uses a binary search algorithm. This method is very efficient, but the implementation has a classic bug: `mid = (low + high) / 2;` can overflow for large arrays, causing undefined behavior. It should be written:

  ```
  mid = low + (high - low) / 2;
  ```